# Kohana orm: insert в несколько таблиц

Tags: kohana, orm, insert

Здравствуйте! Возникли недопонимания в ORM. Я имею три таблицы: persons, birhplace и special_signs.

> persons:  id |    name |  last_name |     patronymic |    birthday |  sex |
>
> birthplace:   id |    person_id |     country |   region |    city |
>
> special_signs:    id |    person_id |     signs |

Таблица persons является основной. Данные в таблицах birthplace и special_signs могут быть добавлены, а могу и нет.

Соответственно, создаю три модели:

```
//person.php
class Model_Person  extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'persons';
}

//birthplace.php
class Model_Birthplace  extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'birthplace';
}

//specialsigns.php
class Model_Specialsigns  extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'special_signs';
}
```

Теперь в контроллере Person я обрабатываю входные данные:

```
public function action_save(){

        if(isset($_POST['save_btn']))){
            if(isset($_POST['person'])){
                $person = Validation::factory($_POST['person'])
                ->rule('name','not_empty')
                ->rule('last_name','not_empty')
                ->rule('patronymic','not_empty')
                ->rule('birthday',array($this,'check_date'),array(':validation',':field',':value'))
                ->rule('sex','digit')

                if($person->check()){
                    $person_save = ORM::factory('persons');
                    $person_save->values(array(
                        'name'          => HTML::entities(strip_tags($person['name'])),
                        'last_name'     => HTML::entities(strip_tags($person['last_name'])),
                        'patronymic'    => HTML::entities(strip_tags($person['patronymic'])),
                        'birthday'      => $this->build_date($person['birthday']),
                        'sex'           => (($person['sex'] == 0) ? 'famale' : 'male'), 
                        )
                    )->save();

                    //$person_save->id;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

И, вопрос! Как сохранить данные в birthplace и special_signs? Будет ли правильно, после добавления данных в таблицу persons написать:

```
//Проводим валидацию массива birthplace, если он не пуст, то добавляем данные.

ORM::factory('birthplace')->values(
    'person_id' => $person_save->id
     ......
);

//Проводим валидацию массива special_signs, если он не пуст, то добавляем данные.

ORM::factory('special_signs')->values(
    'person_id' => $person_save->id
     ......
);
```

Или для таких целей используют Query_Builder? Что можете посоветовать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правильно мыслите. Я бы делал так:

```
 $db = Database::instance();
 try {
    $db->begin();
    $person_save->save();
    //здесь $person_save->id уже заполнен
    $person_save->save_birthplace($_POST); // сохраняем зависимые записи
    $person_save->save_specialsigns($_POST);

    $db->commit();
    $this->request->redirect( $this->object_list_url );
} catch ( Kohana_ORM_Validation_Exception $ex ) {
    $view->errors = $ex->errors("models");
    $db->rollback();
}
```

И в модель добавить функции save_birthplace() и save_specialsigns().
Если сохранение связанных записей не удастся, транзакцию можно будет откатить.